# You have an error in your SQL syntax when using docker exec rest api

Tags: mysql

I try to run a mysql statement via docker exec api -> https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.41/#operation/ContainerExec

My Statement looks like this

```
{
    "AttachStdin": false,
    "AttachStdout": true,
    "AttachStderr": true,
    "DetachKeys": "ctrl-p,ctrl-q",
    "Tty": false,
    "Cmd": [
        "bin/bash","-c", "mysql -uroot -ptesttest -e 'INSERT INTO `mandator_1`.`terminal` (`serialNumber`, `name`, `isActive`, `status`, `profileId`, `businessId`, `divisionId`, `ipAddress`, `groupId`, `setupVersion`, `macAddress`, `authType`) VALUES ('54321', '54321', '1', NULL, '1', '1', NULL, '172.45.17.197', '1', NULL, 'E4-F1-D3-FD', '2');' mandator_1"
    ]
}
```

but when i run the statement i get an error

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '.17.197, 1, NULL, E4-F1-D3-FD, 2)' at line 1

i think my escaping is wrong but at which point?

Comment: Try to change quote by double quote `VALUES ("54321", "54321", "1", ...., "2");`

Comment: at first that did not help because you also need to escape the double quotes with \, after that it works. Post it as an answer and i'll accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change quote by double quote:

```
VALUES (\"54321\", \"54321\", \"1\", ...., \"2\");
```